# Imagick and html tags

Tags: php, html, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to make a thumbnail image on the go with imagick.

Everything works fine when i use this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$source = "image.jpg";
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage ($source);
$image->cropThumbnailImage( 160, 120 );
echo $image;
?>
```

but when I wrap it with `<html>` and `<body>` tags I get all those strange characters like:

ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿÛC !"$"$ÿÛC

I couldn't find anywhere hot to use imagick with html tags.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put that php code above into a separate file, for example `thumbNail.php`
Then on your html page, you call up the created image, by referencing that file in the `src` attribute like this for example:

```
<img src="thumbNail.php" />
```

You can't put any html markup inside the PHP file, because the browser is expecting to get an image back, not html (This happens because you set the content-type header to an image)